# Delete repeated values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, excel-2013, countif

I have a long list of invoices. The invoice numbers (`BEL_NR` column) are repeated as each one of them contain at least one position, that means that data referring to logistics costs for each invoice is also repeated in column `Frachtkosten`. What I'm trying to do is to delete consecutive repeated values, leaving only the first one.

For example: put `0` in `C3` because `A2` in repeated in `A3`.

I attach a picture of what I intend to do: on the left is what I have, on the right is what I'd like to have. Please note I can't do that manually as the list is so so long.
[image: image of what I want to do]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Row2 of a spare column enter and copy down:

```
=A2=A1
```

Filter that column to select `FALSE`, enter `0` in the first displayed cell (excluding header) for `Frachtkosten` and copy down.

Comment: oh sweet! I just try it out in a try out excel sheet, then after doing what you said I did a =IF(D2=FALSE,C2,0) and it worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

There are many different ways to do this. As stated by @pnuts one solution is to have in column `C3` the formula `=A2=A3` and copy down. This requires the data be sorted on column `A`.

Another solution is (irrespective if column `A` is sorted) is `=(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A2)=0)*1` and copy down